# Keycloak and Spring Boot web app in dockerized environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, oauth-2.0, keycloak

Consider the following environment:

- one docker container is keycloak
- another docker container is our web app that uses keycloak for authentication

The web app is a Spring Boot application with "keycloak-spring-boot-starter" applied. In application.properties:

> keycloak.auth-server-url = http://localhost:8028/auth

A user accessing our web app will be redirected to keycloak using the URL for the exposed port of the keycloak docker container. Login is done without problems in keycloak and the user (browser) is redirected to our web app again. Now, the authorization code needs to be exchanged for an access token. Hence, our web app (keycloak client) tries to connect to the same host and port configured in *keycloak.auth-server-url*. But this is a problem because the web app resides in a docker container and not on the host machine, so it should rather access *http://keycloak:8080* or something where *keycloak* is the linked keycloak docker container.

So the question is: **How can I configure the keycloak client to apply different URLs for browser redirection and access token endpoints?**

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50670734/keycloak-in-docker-compose-network

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There used to be another property `auth-server-url-for-backend-requests` but was [removed by pull request #2506](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/pull/2506) as a solution to [issue #2623 on Keycloak's JIRA](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2623). In the description of this issue, you'll find the reasons why and possible workarounds: *that should be solved at the DNS level or by adding entries to the host file*.

So there is not much you can do in the client configuration, unless you change the code and make your own version of the adapter, but there is something you can do at the Docker level. For this to work properly, first I suggest you use a fully qualified domain name instead of `localhost` for the *public* hostname, as you would in production anyway, eg. `keycloak.mydomain.com`. You can use a fake one (not registered in DNS servers) if you just add it to the host's `/etc/hosts` file (or Windows equivalent) as an alias next to `localhost`.

Then, if you are using Docker Compose, you can set [*aliases*](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#aliases) (alternative hostnames) for the keycloak service on the docker network to which the containers are connected (see doc: Compose File reference / Service configuration reference / networks / aliases). For example:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak
    networks:
      # Replace 'mynet' with whatever user-defined network you are using or want to use
      mynet:
        aliases:
          - keycloak.mydomain.com

  webapp:
    image: "nginx:alpine"
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
```

If you are just using plain Docker, you can do [the equivalent](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#ip-address-and-hostname) with `--alias` flag of `docker network connect` command (see doc: Container networking / IP address and hostname).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While I am testing this approach I have to expose the keycloak port on 8080 to my docker host because the port must be same for access from browser and from my webapp. So I need to assume this port is always available on the docker host, or do I miss something?

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the same port be used in both cases (access from browser outside or from webapp docker container). You could use different ports, eg. by putting the webapp behind a reverse-proxy that rewrites "Location" headers (eg. Nginx + http_proxy_module's proxy_redirect directive) to just change the keycloak server port (and nothing else) in the proxied redirect responses from the webapp, but I'm not sure whether Keycloak will accept getting code/token on one port, then reusing it on another. To be tested.

Comment: This is perfect for testing a compose environment on your local machine with keycloak. Thank you!

Comment: To make testing for non techies even easier if set up an dns entry like localhost.mydomain.com pointing to 127.0.0.1 - as long as people are online it works without modifying their /etc/hosts file