# Keycloak can not access when running inside a docker-compose network

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, keycloak

I'm trying to use Keycloak quick starts in https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts.

I ran app-nodejs-html5 (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-nodejs-html5) , Keycloak 20.0.1 & service-nodejs (https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/service-nodejs) all inside a docker-compose.

The front end app 'app-nodejs-html5' & key cloak server communication happen without an issue. But API service 'service-nodejs' & keycloak server communication not working properly. When I try to access API from frontend it every time return HTTP code 403.

When I move out service from docker-compose to outside all apps are working fine.

I suspect when both service & keycloak are in docker-compose, API service trying to access Keycloak using both http://localhost:3001 & http://keycloak.local:8080 URL's.

I tried using Frontend URL but that didn't work either.

I tried adding aliases & it didn't work too. ref : [Keycloak and Spring Boot web app in dockerized environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57213611/keycloak-and-spring-boot-web-app-in-dockerized-environment)

Did anyone succeed running keycloak & API service inside a docker compose ?

Extract from docker-compose

```
keycloak:
      # keycloak admin console is available at http://localhost:3001/admin
      image: keycloak:20.0.1
      build:
         context: .
         dockerfile: Dockerfile.keycloak
      container_name: keycloak
      hostname: keycloak.local
      ports:
         - "3001:8080"
         - "3002:8443"
      environment:
         KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
         KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: "false"
         KC_DB: postgres
         KC_DB_USERNAME: dba
         KC_DB_PASSWORD: password
         KC_DB_SCHEMA: public
         KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://database.local:5432/
         KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
         KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: password
      entrypoint: /opt/keycloak/bin/kc.sh start-dev
      depends_on:
         - database
```

Comment: Could you try to add `-hostname-strict-backchannel=false` to the entrypoint after `start-dev`?

Comment: This option didn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Keycloak has some trouble with portfowarding of containers so just change ports to its default port and it will work

```
  ports:
     - "8080:8080"
     - "3002:8443"
```